# fetch data's from existing collection

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a MongoDB database named: "helsinki_city_bike" and I uploaded CSV data using MongoDB compass in the collection name: "journey_detail". I also connected the database to atlas using a connection string.  Now that I want to fetch the data from the database it's creating another test db and collection name "journey_detail" inside "helsinki_city_bike".
how can I fetch data from my collection without creating an empty collection?
the function is working well as I am getting an empty array. what I am doing wrong with the model?

This is my schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const journeySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Departure_time: String,
  Return_time: String,
  Departure_Station_Id: Number,
  Departure_Station_Name: String,
  Return_Station_Id: Number,
  Return_Station_Name: String,
  Covered_Distance: Number,
  Duration: Number,
});

export const journey_detail = mongoose.model("journey_detail", journeySchema);
```

req function:

```
import { journey_detail } from "../models/Schema.js";

export const getJourneyDetails = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const JourneyDetails = await journey_detail.find().limit(10);

    if (!JourneyDetails) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Journey Details not found" });
    }
    res.status(200).json(JourneyDetails);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error retrieving Journey Details" });
  }
};
```

connection:

```
const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", router);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(3001, () => console.log(`server running on the port ${3001}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

mongoose.set();

mongoose.connection.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose connected.");
});
```

Comment: Does the `CONNECTION_URL` include the database name?

Comment: yes  and i had to add mongoose.set("strictQuery", false) and its working. 
but not sure why have to put  strictQuery", false